# Querying post ID from posts starting with specific character

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to query posts starting with specific letter from my array.

Here is what I came up with :

```
$first_char = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0');

$postids = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
                SELECT      ID
                FROM        $wpdb->posts
                WHERE       SUBSTR($wpdb->posts.post_title,1,1) IN (%s)
                ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_title",$first_char));
```

then my WP Query looks like :

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(       
 'post__in' => $postids,
        ));
```

But for some reason $postid returns only values from the first character in $first_char array.